# autoresize div when side bar expand using jquery animate

Tags: jquery, html, css

im trying to achieve the effects used in this website http://www.qvivo.com/. The jquery is working fine, my problem now is how to autoresize the main content when the left panel/sidebar expands. please help guys. thank you in advance.

Comment: In my case I would just use % and display: none. And making a good HTML skeleton. As there is no code, I can't tell more.

Comment: The right side is responsive, the left side is fixed. Research responsive design.

Comment: here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/ytsejam/hqNee/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Liam from QVIVO here. I've written a quick jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/fZy6z/) to mimic the framework of the site.

My main advice is try to let the browser do most of the work for you. Instead of animating DOM with JQuery we simply added and removed class tags with CSS transitions. You won't see the benefit initially but when you start to fill the right panel with a complex DOM tree you'll find the only way to animate smoothly is through hardware accelerated transitions.

Regarding your issue of autoresizing the main content, it's quite simple - never declare a width value for your containing divs as they will auto-stretch to the width of the page anyway. Content within these divs can then be given a width value of 100%.

Cheers,
Liam

Answer (score 1):

I am not the best with Jquery, So I  mix it a little bit with JavaScript.

You will need to play with the Width % of what you want and look.

from your CSS, First I put the class pannel_button I put it Absoute. Also I remove the float left

```
.panel_button{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url(images/arrow.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: thin solid #CCC;
    margin-left: -1px;
    top: 200px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Then for your Jquery ands some of my JavaScript, as I am better in JS, I made the animation this way

```
var content = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
$('.panel_button').click(function()
{
    $(".panel").animate({width:'toggle'},500); 

    if( content[0].style.width=="70%" ){ 
        $(".content").animate({width:"90%"},500);
           $(".panel_button").animate({left:"0%"},500); 
    }
    else{  $(".content").animate({width:"70%"},500);
           $(".panel_button").animate({left:"29%"},500); 
          }
});
```

But Like I said, you will need to play with the Width and positon to make your button where you want it really. And also, remove the float left for your Hover.